# django Model filter by list

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-models, filter

i am getting list of value from checked checkbox , Now i want to filter the list with my model and get only filter result of value in list

```
views.py
def ResultTest(request):
    var = request.POST.get('selectedTests')
    var1 = BookTest.objects.filter(test=v)
   return render(request, 'posts/result.html',{'var1':var1})
```

```
html file
    <div class="col-md-12" style="overflow: auto;">
        <input type="hidden" id="selectedTests" name="selectedTests">
        <input type="hidden" name="test_type" value="pathology">
        <table id="example" class="display" >
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Sr.No</th>
                    <th>Select</th>
                    <th>Test</th>
                    <th>MRP</th>
                    <th>CC Rate</th>


                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

                {% for booktest in contact_list %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ booktest.number }}
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="{{ booktest.test }}" class="chkbox"/> </td>             
                    <td>{{ booktest.test }}</td>
                    <td>{{ booktest.mrp }} </td>
                    <td>{{ booktest.rate }}</td>



                </tr>


               {% endfor %}
            </tbody>

        </table>
```

i am getting the selectedTests a list of values now i want the list of values to filter in models and get all data of the values.

Comment: Exactly what value is stored in the `selectedTests` (what format)? I'm not really sure using a hidden field here is a good idea, since that it can easily be maniipulated.

Comment: actually its a checkbox checked value is store in selectedTests so user checks muliple checkbox so i get a list of values of checked checkbox in selectedTests , Now i want to filter it according to the list of value stored in selectedTests

Comment: ok, and what is the format of the *value*? Is it `"1,2,3,4"`, or `"1 2 3 4"` or something else? Why not send the values of the checkboxes directly?

Comment: the value is in "1,2,3,4"

Answer (score 0):

You can try to split the values by a comma:

```
def result_test(request):
    selected = request.POST.get('selectedTests')
    if selected is not None:
        try:
            booktests = BookTest.objects.filter(test__in=selected.split(','))
        except ValueError:
            # … (1)
        else:
            return render(request, 'posts/result.html',{'var1':booktest})
    else:
        # … (2)
```

You will need to return some HTTP result for (1) (when the format is not respected), and (2) when the request does not contain a `selectedTests` value in the first place.

That being said, it might be better to just define the checkboxes as:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="selectedTests[]" /> option 1
<input type="checkbox" name="selectedTests[]" /> option 2
```

such that you do not have to rely on JavaScript to inject the selected values in the hidden input element.

Comment: Sorry as i am new to django it will sound silly how can i use { 'var1':booktest } in my django template. so that i can get all the related values

Comment: @SumeetSingh: in the template that you render `var1` is a set of `BookTest` objects, so you can for example iterate over these, and write `{% for booktest in var1 %} ... {% endfor %}` and render the booktests in between the `{% for ... %}` and `{% endfor %}`. See for example: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#for

Comment: I tried the following above but i am getting the result of only first value in list for example if the list is of [1,2,3,4] i ma getting only value of 1 in my django template

Comment: Thank You so much @WillemVanOnsem it worked just some minor changes in model and it worked

Comment: is there any way we can store these list in django database its shows error multivalue dict error.

Comment: @SumeetSingh: what list? A `MultiValueeDictError`, means you access a value from a `QueryDict` like `request.GET` and `request.POST`, but the key does not exists. That ican not arise from this. For example you wrote `request.POST['mykey']`, but `mykey` does not exists in `request.POST`.

Comment: selected = request.POST.get('selectedTests') - I tried to save these in my django database like request.POST['selected'] am i doing something wrong?

Comment: @SumeetSingh: well as said before, if the form does not submit that field, then it is not in the POST headers, heance it is missing. It however might be better to ask a new question, and provide the details of what you aim to do, and what problems you face.